# Hidden data to retrieve with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP document where I output some data. I would like to make this data invisible and use jQuery to retrieve different parts of it.

The question is, if I output the data on the same page, can it be made invisible when page source is viewed? Or do I need to keep it on a separate page all together and use AJAX to retrieve and show on my presentation page?

Comment: why output it at all? you do not have to 'store' data 'in' a page. you could just store in a javascript variable(s) and it'll never be visible anywhere except a debugger.

Comment: Do you really need to send that "invisible" data to the client? You can also save data in the php session's variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't hide something completely from the client if you have sent that information to them. If you want it to appear on the client's screen, it will always be accessible to that client. You could use an AJAX request to retrieve the information from another source, but the client could still make the same request manually if they felt like it, and retrieve the same data.

If you want to hide data, don't send it to the client.

If what you really mean is you don't want it to draw the client's attention, then follow Marc B's suggestion and simply have it stored in the javascript until it needs to be placed on the page.

Comment: +1 Ajax request is the only way to keep data completely hidden from the client until requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data in a Hidden field.. this will be visible only in the Markup..

But if you are talking in terms of security where in you do not want the data to be displayed unless requested for , it is better to store it on the server and retrieve it by sending an ajax request..

Answer (score -1):

it all depends on the structure html. You can use jquery .show() and .hide() when you want.

Example, if you receive:

```
<span id="first">Hello world 1</span>
<span id="second">Hello world 2</span>


<script>

//you handle it as you like
$("#first").show();
$("#second").hide();


//or

$("#first").hide();
$("#second").show();

<script>
```

Comment: OP wants to hide the data completely so it's not viewable at all to the user until it's requested, not even in the source code.